# Source for removing tefillin straps from your hands for hagbah

Tags: tefilin, sefer-torah, hagbah-gelilah

I was told by many people that, if one is wearing tefillin, he should remove the straps of tefillin from his hand before lifting the Torah for *hagbah* so that they are not in the same place as the Torah handles. I have seen nearly every man in my Ashkenazi Orthodox synagogue do this.

What is the source of such a practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 1967, R. Efraim Greenblatt published an extensive article on the laws of *Gelilah* in the journal *Noam* (vol 10). He writes there as follows:

> נוהגין בעת שגוללין מוריד הגולל את רצועות התפילין מאצבעותיו וטעם לזה לא מצאתי ובספר בית ברוך אשר על החיי אדם ח"ב בדף של"ב כתב משום שקל יותר לגלול בלי הרצועות וכן ידידי הרב אזבאנד כתב דיוכל לתפוס יותר טוב וזה כבוד הספר וידידי הרה"ג ר"ח ראזין שליט"א כתב לי בזה ואפשר עוד כי הלא לקיחה ע"י דבר אחר שמה לקיחה כמבואר בסוכה סופ"ג ואם תהיינה הרצועות על גבי אצבעותיו נמצא הפעולה שהוא עושה פעולת הגלילה עושה גם ברצועות ונמצא דמשתמש גם ברצועות וידידי הגר"י פורת שליט"א כתב לי מה שבעלי הגבהה וגלילה מסירים הרצועות מעל אצבעותיהם פשוט שכך יותר נח לאחוז בעצי חיים ולגלול ובשיחה עם ידידי הרה"ג ר' מרדכי וילגער שליט"א נתעורר אצלנו שאולי יש בזה משום אין עושין מצות חבילות חבילות וידידי הרה"ג הרב הדאייה שליט"א כתב לי בזה מה שמורידין הרצועות הוא משלש טעמים אחת שלא יפריע להם באחיזת הס"ת הרצועות של האצבע שלא יוכל להחזיק הס"ת טוב כשהרצועות על האצבע מכיון שמפסיקין בין האצבע לס"ת ואולי יש חשש שתשמט הס"ת ב טעם שני אולי מפני קדושת הרצועות של התפילין שלא ישתמש בהם להחזקת הס"ת ג משום חציצה שצריך שלא יהא דבר חוצץ בין ידו להס"ת ע"ד מה שעושים הכהנים בזמן ב"כ ואאמו"ר שליט"א אמר כ"כ דבפשטות נראה שאז יותר קל לגלול והרה"ג ר' שלמה סאבל שליט"א אמר בזה שכתוב שבחו"ל שמניחים תפילין בחוה"מ יסירו את הרצועות בשעת נטילת לולב משום

Instead of translating, let me summarize the suggestions that he offers for this custom:

1. It makes it easier to roll the Torah
2. It makes it easier to hold the Torah more firmly (and thus decreases the likelihood that the Torah will slip)
3. Because "using" the straps of the tefillin for another purpose [even a mitzvah, presumably] is not so respectful
4. Perhaps there is an aspect of 'doing mitzvot in bundles,' that we generally try to avoid fulfilling multiple mitzvot together, as if they are a burden
5. Perhaps it is better that there not be a separation between a person's hands when they are performing a mitzvah, just like for kohanim when they bless the congregation
6. To "make the mitzvah [of hagbah/gelilah] more complete"
7. Actually, there is no 'custom' to do this, and some people just do so for the sake of comfort

Comment: Very nice find, +1

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. I don't do this and always thought those doing it were doing so for convenience. I see AskTheRav.com [writes](https://asktherav.com/2729-tefillin-straps-during-hagba/) the same (they are affiliated with the Beis Din of Crown Heights and with the Va’ad Hakohol of Crown Heights)

> There is no requirement to remove tefillin straps when doing Hagbah;
> it’s purely for convenience.

(see further there for sources)

Although R Ari Enkin [quotes](https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/gelila/2024/01/24/) Rivevot V’yovlot 3:2:7 that

> one should remove the strap both for comfort as well as to avoid
> having an interposition between one’s hands and the Torah

Comment: thanks! The "explanation" seems very strange to me though, since I don't understand why 'having an interposition between one's hands and the Torah' is prohibited. Unfortunately I don't have access to Rivevos V'yovlos volume 3 (next time I'm in Memphis...)

Comment: Seems strange to me as well. I don’t completely understand why the contact with the wood of the Torah holder matters so much.